# I am new to python i tried to run this fancy decorators code

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, decorator

```
class Square:
    def _init_(self,side):
        self._side = side
    @property
    def side(self):
        return self._side
    @side.setter
    def side(self,value):
        if value >= 0:
            self._side = value
        else:
            print("error")
    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._side **2
    @classmethod
    def unit_square(cls):
        return cls(1)
s = Square(5)
print(s.side)
print(s.area)
```

but i am getting error ( s = Square(5) TypeError: Square() takes no arguments) i am not able to figure it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this constructor takes no arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929872/this-constructor-takes-no-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The `init` method should have double underscores(`__`). Change the method to `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, side):
    self._side = side
```

Reference: https://dbader.org/blog/python-dunder-methods